# Limit users to their own employees

Tags: permissions, custom-list, excel

I have a list of about 1000 employees with their addresses and phone numbers which I want to upload to a 2007 SharePoint in list format, which I know how to do, however due to data protection, managers are only able to view their own employees details.

For example, I have John Smith and his contact number is 12345678987, his manager is Joe Bloggs. I will upload this through an excel sheet to my SharePoint where everyone can access this information, however I do not want a different manager to see John Smith's details.

The SharePoint is linked to our network and uses the managers logins, is this something I can use to limit the access?

Comment: If this cannot be achieved with Excel, can it be achieved with Access?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want actual security in place, then you should break the inheritance and provide item level permission.

i.e give explicit permission to manager Joe Bloggs to all employee items where Joe Bloggs is the manager.

Another option is to create a View which filter "Manager = Current User". And remove all other views. Don't give permissions to managers to modify the view. This way managers will only see their employee details.

Comment: Ok great thank you for the quick response, however how would I give the manager access to his employees on bulk? I will also need to update the SharePoint weekly with a data, this will mean uploading another excel sheet. Wont this break the permission levels?

Comment: In that case I think the View approach will be easier.

Comment: Thats great, however how do I make it show only current user? I have changed the view options to limit only when "manager = current user" but what do I enter in this cell for it to look for the current user? And what do I enter into the managers cell. Their login? Or their full name? Bit complicated to explain without showing you :)

Comment: You can create view and filter Manager Field "equals" [Me]

Comment: Brilliant, now how do I change the manager column to be a 'Person or Group' type, as this was uploaded from Excel

Comment: I have never tried that. I would suggest you automate this process using Powershell. Create a powershell script which read the excel from a predefined path and insert into sharepoint list. Then schedule the script to run every x days.

Comment: My experience with Powershell is nill. Would Microsoft Access work?